# Conflicting javascript hides dropdown list elements

Tags: javascript, html

There are 2 scripts on a page. One enables dropdowns in the horizontal navigation bar. The other allows expandable lists in 2 levels below the navbar. On this page the list items in the navbar that contain dropdowns are missing, displaying only the menu items without dropdowns.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
    stuHover = function() {
    var cssRule;
    var newSelector;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
        for (var x = 0; x < document.styleSheets[i].rules.length ; x++)
            {
            cssRule = document.styleSheets[i].rules[x];
            if (cssRule.selectorText.indexOf("LI:hover") != -1)
            {
                 newSelector = cssRule.selectorText.replace(/LI:hover/gi, "LI.iehover");
                document.styleSheets[i].addRule(newSelector , cssRule.style.cssText);
            }
        }
    var getElm = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i=0; i<getElm.length; i++) {
        getElm[i].onmouseover=function() {
            this.className+=" iehover";
        }
        getElm[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" iehover\\b"), "");
        }
    }
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", stuHover);
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        $('li').not(".drop_down" )
            .css('pointer','default')
            .css('list-style-image','none');
        $('li:has(ul)').not( ".drop_down" )
            .click(function(event){
                if (this == event.target) {
                    $(this).css('list-style-image',
                        (!$(this).children().is(':hidden')) ? 'url(images/plusbox.gif)' : 'url(images/minusbox.gif)');
                    $(this).children().toggle('100');
                }
                //return false;
            })
            .css({cursor:'pointer', 'list-style-image':'url(images/plusbox.gif)'})
            .children().hide();
        $('li:not(:has(ul))').not( ".drop_down" ).css({cursor:'default', 'list-style-image':'none'});

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="topnav">
        <p>Horizontal navigation bar</p>
        <p>The styled page does not show the + symbols in the navbar. Menu items with no dropdowns move left to occupy the space that should be occupied by elements with dropdown lists.</p>                    
        <ul id="nav">
            <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>Item 1</span></a></li>
            <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span>Item 2</span></a></li>


            <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span class="down">Item 3</span></a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li style="margin:10px 0; font-size:1rem; font-style:italic; ">Bicycle</li>
                    <li><a href="#">3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3-2</a></li>                                
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span class="down">Item 4</span></a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#">4-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank">4-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>                        
            <li class="top"><a href="#" class="top_link"><span class="down">Item 5</span></a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#">5-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">5-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">5-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="top"><a href="#"class="top_link"><span>Contact</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:24px"> 
        <p>Expandable lists</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Level 1
                <ul>
                    <li>Level 2
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
            <li>Level 1
                <ul>
                    <li>Level 2
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Help?

Comment: Why u no use jQuery when you've already included jQuery?

Comment: I don't know javascript or jquery so I searched for scripts online and pasted them into the page. Lame, I know, but I didn't want to spend endless time learning what I know nothing about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second javascript on the page, the jQuery, is hiding the children of list items (li's), specifically the li's that have ul. You need to change the not selector in the jQuery code to ignore the first ul.

Instead of `.not( ".drop_down" )`

Use `.not(".top" )`

[Here is a fiddle with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/mWyDt/)